# How to select the "best" new point when sampling a near-parabolic function?

Tags: performance, algorithm, wolfram-mathematica, sampling, approximation

The objective function is guaranteed to be finite and contionuous in the interpolation range `[a, b]` along with its first and second derivatives and has no more than one minimum in this range (if it has no minimum it is monotonic). The function has no narrow peak in the interpolation range and generally is close to parabola `y = a*x + b*x^2` (but is not exactly a parabola). Please suggest an iterative algorithm (and interpolation method) of selecting the "best" new sampling point (starting from the points `a` and `b`) for constructing an interpolating function which approximates the objective function with prescribed relative accuracy at any point in the range `[a, b]` (at least with reasonable probability). The function is very expensive to compute and so the number of function evaluations (sampling points) should be minimal. At the same time, the complexity of the algorithm is not important.

Comment: Chebyshev interpolation looks very efficient here, since derivatives seem to decrease very fast (provided your function is indeed smooth). No clue about how to do it with Mathematica however.

Comment: @Alexandre My function is guaranteed to be two times continuously differentiable in the interpolation range. But the first (and main) point of the question is the choice of sampling points at which the objective function will be evaluated. The function is very expensive to evaluate and so the number of evaluations (sampling points) should be minimal. At the same time, the complexity of the algorithm is not important.

Comment: Chebyshev interpolation will give you the sample points. It will be very efficient (ie. a very few points will guarantee good approximation for both f and f', and it is "almost optimal" as a polynomial approximation), but you have to know that your function is more than C^2. Chebyshev interpolation works very well when the function is very smooth.

Comment: @Alexandre It seems that with Chebyshev interpolation I must specify the number of optimal sampling points `n` which I do not know (for different functions `n` will be different for getting the same accuracy of interpolation). Even worse, with different `n` I get completely different sets of points (i.e. I cannot efficiently reuse already computed points if the accuracy is insufficient).

Comment: Indeed. I was assuming that you could content with a fixed number of points. How are you planning to measure the quality of the interpolation ?

Comment: @Alexandre I am not deeply in this field but probably at each stage of the process newly computed point is compared with the value we have got from interpolating function with having only already computed points (without the new point). Having the assumptions about the objective function I described in the question it is probably possible to develop a method allowing to guarantee (or at least to state it with reasonable probability) that the relative error in any point in the interpolation interval will be less than prescribed quantity.

Comment: @Alexandre Probably such methods are already developed: the problem looks quite common and trivial.

Comment: The problem thus amounts to selecting the "best" new point. I'm afraid I cannot be of any help beyond this point. In any case you should state this clearly in the question in case someone with the right knowledge could help.